# How to filter splitting a column value?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, python

I´m a newbie in the SQL world and I code with just the simple insert, select, delete and update.

So... I have a table with a column named "market" that has a list of cryptocoins... like this...

```
market
-------
EOS/ETH    
EOS/BTC
XMR/BTC
LTC/BTC
DASH/ETH
...
```

I need to select * from this table where:

- the string before the '/' is equal to each other but after the '/' goes ETH and BTC.
- There is a column named exchange that I want to filter too. In this example would be all this coins where exchange = 'bittrex'

In this example the result would be:

```
EOS/ETH 
EOS/BTC
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) like INSTR(), LEFT(), RIGHT(), LENGTH() for this purpose.

> ```
> create table market(id int, col varchar(100), exchange varchar(100));
>
> insert into market values
> (1, 'EOS/ETH',  'bittrex'),
> (2, 'EOS/BTC',  'other'),
> (3, 'EOS/BTC',  'bittrex'),
> (4, 'XMR/BTC',  'other'),
> (5, 'LTC/BTC',  'other'),
> (6, 'DASH/ETH', 'other');
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from   market t1
> where  right(t1.col, length(t1.col) - instr(t1.col, '/')) IN ('ETH','BTC')
> and    exchange = 'bittrex'
> and    exists (select 1
>                from market t2
>                where left(t2.col, instr(t2.col, '/')) = left(t1.col, instr(t1.col, '/'))
>                and right(t2.col, length(t2.col) - instr(t2.col, '/')) IN ('ETH','BTC')
>                and   exchange = 'bittrex'
>                group by left(t2.col, instr(t2.col, '/'))
>                having count(*) > 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | col     | exchange
> -: | :------ | :-------
>  1 | EOS/ETH | bittrex 
>  3 | EOS/BTC | bittrex
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e24184415863296ef6c8a2c58be6fd6e)*

As Rick James has pointed out on his comments you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX() and get the same result.

> ```
> select *
> from   market t1
> where  substring_index(t1.col, '/', -1) IN ('ETH','BTC')
> and    exchange = 'bittrex'
> and    exists (select   1
>                from     market t2
>                where    substring_index(t2.col, '/', 1) = substring_index(t1.col, '/', 1)
>                and      substring_index(t1.col, '/', -1) IN ('ETH','BTC')
>                and      exchange = 'bittrex'
>                group by substring_index(t1.col, '/', -1)
>                having   count(*) > 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | col     | exchange
> -: | :------ | :-------
>  1 | EOS/ETH | bittrex 
>  3 | EOS/BTC | bittrex
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a628025556ac0d90408610121e57f5f2)*

Comment: Suggest the code would be simpler by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.

Answer (score 0):

This REGEXP is another simplification.

```
SELECT * from tbl
    FROM ( SELECT market, exchange
                 SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '/', 1) AS lft
            FROM tbl
            WHERE col REGEXP "(ETH|BTC)$"
              AND exchange = 'bittrex'
            GROUP BY lft
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
         ) AS x
    JOIN tbl  USING (market, exchange)
```